# IOS delegate function not getting called

Tags: ios, delegates, core-location

DISCLAIMER: My terminology when talking about delegates might be a little off.

I've been debugging this for a few hours now and haven't gotten anywhere, though I've found some interesting behavior. Basically I have a UIViewController (VC) with a custom NSObject (NSO) instance as a property. I've created a delegate in the NSO object so that it can talk/call functions in the VC. I've done this before so I thought it'd be no problem, but when I try to call the delegate functions from the NSO object the VC does not receive the calls.

Here is my interface for the NSO class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@protocol ServerDBDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void) func;

@end


@interface ServerDB : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ServerDBDelegate> delegate;


@end
```

The NSO object uses CoreLocation and I call the VC delegate functions from one of the CoreLocation delegate functions, specifically...

```
 -(void)locationManager: didUpdateLocations: {
      [self.delegate func];
 }
```

If this is confusing leave a comment and I'll clarify.

Since the VC never receives the call I put in this line into the function above.

```
NSLog(self.delegate == nil ? @"Nil" : @"Not nil");
```

And this prints 'Nil' every single time so I figured I wasn't setting up my delegates correctly. After more debugging I still thought I was doing the delegate stuff correctly so I overwrote the setter for the delegate to see if it was getting set correctly at some point.

```
- (void) setDelegate:(id<ServerDBDelegate>)delegate {
    _delegate = delegate;
    NSLog(self.delegate == nil ? "Nil2" : "Not Nil2");
}
```

When the setter was called it outputed 'Not Nil2' and then a split second later I saw the output 'Nil' from the CoreLocation delegate function. So I thought that I initially set the delegate correctly but then at some point it gets overwritten to nil. Okay my last step.

```
- (void) setDelegate:(id<ServerDBDelegate>)delegate {
    _delegate = delegate;
    [self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:self afterDelay:3];
}

- (void) test {
   NSLog(self.delegate == nil ? "Nil2" : "Not Nil2");
}

-(void)locationManager: didUpdateLocations: {
    NSLog(self.delegate == nil ? "Nil" : "Not Nil");
    [self test];
}
```

Important to know, the locationManager function gets called a few times a second. So when I run this I see this output

```
Nil
Nil2
Nil
Nil2
Nil
Nil2
Nil
Nil2
Not Nil2
Nil
Nil2
```

So it looks like the delegate isn't set, yet when I call test: from the setter after a delay it is still set, but only in the scope of that function. I truly don't know how to proceed or where the bug might be. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where/how are you declaring your _delegate?

Comment: I'll add it in as an edit.

Comment: What are you assigning as the delegate? Does that class conform to your delegate?

Comment: The VC's declaration looks like this:
@interface ViewBarsViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ServerDBDelegate>

and I set the NSO instances delegate to the UIViewController

Comment: How did you called the `setDelegate` method?

Comment: the instance name of the NSO object in the VC is server so I did self.server.delegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the way a delegate works.
But before going further I have a question: you are not using ARC? I see that you've used `retain` on your delegate property.

Either way, if you use `retain` for your delegate property (which is `strong` under ARC) instead of `weak` you'll create a **retain cycle**.

Now back to your issue:

1. It's OK how you've declared the protocol and the delegate (except for the fact that it should be assign or weak under ARC).
2. This method looks almost OK to me:

   `-(void)locationManager: didUpdateLocations: {
         [self.delegate func];
   }`

But as a good practice you should always check if your delegate `respondsToSelector`. So put an `if` statement wrapping up the `[self.delegate func]` like so: `if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(func)]){self.delegate func];}`

3. When you want to conform to a delegate, in the class that should conform to it you must add the `ServerDBDelegate` to its interface declaration like this:

   `@interface myClass: superclass <ServerDBDelegate>`
4. After you declare that your Class should conform to `ServerDBDelegate` you must become the delegate of that class by calling something like:

`[[ServerDB sharedManager] setDelegate: self]; //example of a singleton class setDelegate call.`

or have a ServerDB property (nonatomic, strong) in the class that conforms to the ServerDBDelegate, instantiate it somewhere in your class (`viewDidLoad` would be a good candidate) or do a lazy instantiation and become the delegate of the ServerDB class like this:

Header file (.h):

```
@interface myClassViewController: UIViewController <ServerDBDelegate>
@end
```

Implementation file (.m)

```
    @interface myClassViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) ServerDB *dbInstance; //hold a strong reference to the ServerDBClass
    @end

    @implementation myClassViewController

    //lazy instantiation
    - (ServerDB *)dbInstance {
      if (_dbInstance) {return _dbInstance;}
      _dbInstance = [[ServerDB alloc] init];
      return _dbInstance;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       self.dbInstance.delegate = self; //here you make myClassViewController a delegate of your ServerDB class
    }

    //add and define the required method from your delegate protocol
    - (void)func {
      NSLog(@"ServerDB called me: %@",NSStringFromSelector:@selector(_cmd));
    }
    @end
```

Now, whenever you make an action in the ServerDB class that makes a call to the delegate 'func' method, the delegate will call your 'func' method defined in the myClassViewController.

Comment: Too be honest I think I do all of the above. I changed retain to assign in my delegate declaration but that had no effect.

Comment: Are you making your ViewController Class a delegate of your ServerDB by assigning self to the ServerDBDelegate like I did in viewDidLoad or in a segue?

Comment: Yes, and when I overwrote the delegate setter I put in a call to a delegate function in the VC right after I manually set the delegate and it worked.